# How to use pattern and group in property mediator to validate

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

how to use pattern and group for validating property.

```
<property name="string" [action=set|remove] [type="string"] 
(value="literal" | expression="xpath") 
[scope=default|transport|axis2|axis2-client] [pattern="regex" 
[group="integer"]]>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pattern in Property mediator can be used to match the value or the result of an expression against a given pattern. If the pattern matches, Property mediator returns the value. Else, it returns an empty string.

For example, in the following example, only Test1 property value matches with the pattern. Hence, only Test1 returns the value. Test2 returns an empty string.

```html
<property name="Test1" value="5" scope="default" type="STRING" pattern="[0-9]" group="0"/>
<property name="Test2" value="20" scope="default" type="STRING" pattern="[0-9]" group="0"/>
<log level="custom">
    <property name="Test1 Value : " expression="get-property('Test1')"/>
    <property name="Test2 Value : " expression="get-property('Test2')"/>
</log>
```

[image]

And, "group" attribute in Property mediator is intended to be used to evaluate against the number of capturing groups in this matcher's pattern, similar to java.util.regex.Matcher.groupCount() in Java. However, apparently the group support is not available in WSO2 EI 6.5.0 at the moment.

Comment: We have fixed the mentioned group related issue in Property mediator. It will be available in the upcoming release. https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/pull/1379